# signalR interrupted while the page was loading error when navigating from a page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

When navigating away from a page that has signalR connection/connected hub I get the following error message.

> **The connection to** "http://localhost:53604/signalr/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionId=0b308c0d-2122-4e60-a9fa-f6e3f3eb1f4e&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22packageactionstatus%20%22%7D%5D&tid=9" **was interrupted while the page was loading**.

I do understand that the connection was lost (which is Ok) due to navigating away from the page but is there a safe way to stop the connection before navigating away from the current page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can close the connection onunload:

```
$.connection.hub.stop();
```

Though I'm not sure why do you care of this error.

Comment: should I assume that once I lave a page that has the connection, the connection is severed? correct?

Comment: @ShaneKm. Your assumption is correct as much as I'm aware of. HTTP is stateless.

Answer (score 5):

To do this properly you want to trap the **onbeforeunload** event, and you want to do it like so:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $.connection.hub.stop();
};
```

Fixed the problem for me with firefox.